# makeStyles() throwing error using Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Good Evening,
I am trying to convert my JS react application to React Typescript, but I am running into a very long error. I am not sure how to get past this. Below is the code in the file its referencing and how I am implementing it, as well as the error.

I am new to Typescript and I have tried other solutions from other Stackoverflow posts, but none to see to have worked. I was originally using `creatStyles()`, but that does not seem to work either.

If I changed the implementation of `useStyles` to

```js
//const useStyles = makeStyles<DefaultTheme>((theme: Theme) => {createStyles(appStyle)});
```

Then the error I get tells me that `theme:Theme => void`

Any guidance is appreciated

```js
TypeScript error in /Users/augustshah/Documents/Coding-Tools-new/Projects/Payment-Dashboard/src/layouts/Admin.tsx(43,30):
Argument of type '(theme: Theme) => { wrapper: { position: string; top: string; height: string; }; mainPanel: { maxHeight: string; width: string; overflowScrolling: string; transition: string; overflow: string; position: string; float: string; }; content: { ...; }; container: { ...; }; map: { ...; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Styles<Theme, {}, "content" | "map" | "wrapper" | "mainPanel" | "container">'.
  Type '(theme: Theme) => { wrapper: { position: string; top: string; height: string; }; mainPanel: { maxHeight: string; width: string; overflowScrolling: string; transition: string; overflow: string; position: string; float: string; }; content: { ...; }; container: { ...; }; map: { ...; }; }' is not assignable to type 'StyleRulesCallback<Theme, {}, "content" | "map" | "wrapper" | "mainPanel" | "container">'.
    Call signature return types '{ wrapper: { position: string; top: string; height: string; }; mainPanel: { maxHeight: string; width: string; overflowScrolling: string; transition: string; overflow: string; position: string; float: string; }; content: { ...; }; container: { ...; }; map: { ...; }; }' and 'StyleRules<{}, "content" | "map" | "wrapper" | "mainPanel" | "container">' are incompatible.
      The types of 'wrapper' are incompatible between these types.
        Type '{ position: string; top: string; height: string; }' is not assignable to type 'CSSProperties | CreateCSSProperties<{}> | PropsFunc<{}, CreateCSSProperties<{}>>'.
          Type '{ position: string; top: string; height: string; }' is not assignable to type 'CreateCSSProperties<{}>'.
            Types of property 'position' are incompatible.
              Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'PositionProperty | PropsFunc<{}, PositionProperty>'.  TS2345

    41 |   </Switch>
    42 | );
  > 43 | const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => (appStyle(theme)));
       |                              ^
    44 | 
    45 | 
    46 |  //const useStyles = makeStyles<DefaultTheme>((theme: Theme) => {createStyles(appStyle)});
```

**Admin.tsx**

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => (appStyle(theme)));



export default function Admin({ ...rest }) {
  // styles
  //const classes = useStyles();
  const theme = useTheme<Theme>();
  const classes = useStyles(theme);

 
  return (
    <div className={classes.wrapper}>
      {handleSideBarLogin() ?
     null :  <Sidebar
     routes={routes}
     logoText={"02DesignStudio"}
     logo={logo}
     image={image}
     handleDrawerToggle={handleDrawerToggle}
     open={mobileOpen}
     color={color}
     {...rest}
    />
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

**AdminStyle.tsx**

```js
import {
  drawerWidth,
  transition,
  container
} from "../../material-dashboard-react";

const appStyle = theme => ({
  wrapper: {
    position: "relative" as "relative",
    top: "0",
    height: "100vh"
  },
  mainPanel: {
    [theme.breakpoints.up("md")]: {
      width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`
    },
    overflow: "auto",
    position: "relative",
    float: "right",
    ...transition,
    maxHeight: "100%",
    width: "100%",
    overflowScrolling: "touch"
  },
  content: {
    marginTop: "70px",
    padding: "30px 15px",
    minHeight: "calc(100vh - 123px)"
  },
  container,
  map: {
    marginTop: "70px"
  }
});

export default appStyle;
```

**Babel**

```js
module.exports = api => {
    api.cache.forever();
    return {
      "presets": [
        [ "@babel/preset-env", {
          "targets": {
            "node": "8.10"
          }
        }, '@babel/preset-typescript']
      ],
      plugins: [
        "add-react-displayname",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"
      ]
    };
  }
```

**TSconfig**

```js
{
 
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "esnext",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "keyofStringsOnly": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./src"
    ],
    "types": [
      "react",
      "jest",
      "node"
    ],
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
  ],
}
```

**new Error**

```js
src/assets/jss/material-dashboard-react/layouts/adminStyle.tsx
  Line 9:26:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

   7 | const appStyle = theme => ({
   8 |   wrapper: {
>  9 |     position: "relative" as "relative",
     |                          ^
  10 |     top: "0",
  11 |     height: "100vh"
  12 |   },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets have a look at that error.
While it is very long, Typescript helpfully drills down on the exact type mismatch we are having.
Looking at

```
The types of 'wrapper' are incompatible between these types.
Types of property 'position' are incompatible
```

we know that the key `wrapper.position` is the origin of the type mismatch.

Looking further into the last line of the type error:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'PositionProperty | PropsFunc<{}, PositionProperty>'
```

We see that Typescript does not match our type `string` to whatever `PositionProperty` is.

`PositionProperty` is a set of allowed strings, such as `relative` and `absolute`, but typescript thinks our type is `string`, although we defined `position` as `"relative"`:

```
const appStyle = theme => ({
wrapper: {
  position: "relative",
```

This is because of Typescripts [type widening](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/literal-type-widening-in-typescript).
We need to tell typescript that we want the specific type here.
Changing the assignment to

```
const appStyle = theme => ({
wrapper: {
  position: "relative" as "relative", // Tells typescript to use "relative" as type
```

should fix your error.

Comment: Thank you for the very descriptive answer. I made your change and I am getting a parsing error on 'as'. It expects a ','

Comment: Hmm, this should not happen while using Typescript. Can you show a bit more of the code?

Comment: Added my babel, and tsconfig, and changed the wrapper CSS to match whats in my code.

Comment: Can you post the whole error message?

Comment: Added the error. Could it be ESlint?

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind right now is `position: ("relative" as "relative"),`

Comment: Nope that did not work either.

Comment: Well, it seems there were people with pretty much the same problem as you, here are more solutions for you to try: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/8928#issuecomment-340964842

Maybe this'll help you.

Comment: const decorate = withStyles({
  container: {
    position: 'absolute',
    // ...
  },
}

Comment: That solved it for me. I have a new error that's in my tsx. Im going to post a new question if you so choose to help. You have been a tremendous help.

Comment: Link to new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70207098/property-wrapper-does-not-exist-on-type-classnamemapnever-typescript

Answer (score 0):

```js
import {withStyles} from 'materialui/core/styles'
const decorate = withStyles({
  container: {
    position: 'absolute',
    // ...
  },
}
```

Comment: Note that, while switching to `withStyles` hides your problem for now, it may appear later on again. You now have to use higher-order components instead of hooks, which might not be what you want.